# How to enable and collect crash-reports in a website [chromium - ubuntu]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crash, chromium

I'm trying to collect the all crash report from the chromium process which I've started using the command line.

```
chromium --enable-crash-reporter  --crash-dumps-dir=/User/test/chrome_crash  --remote-debugging-port=9222  --enable-logging --v=1
```

But the crash report is not being dumped into the given directory, as I don't see any directory/file got created in the given crash dump directory.